# XAMPP works without php.ini file

Tags: php, xampp

I have xampp server on local computer.

I  rename `php.ini` file as `--php.ini`, then restart apache service, but xampp works fine, php files are running and no error messages displayed...

Can you tell please what may be reason of this?

Comment: Isnt php.ini recreated after restart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably renaming the wrong `php.ini` file. To find the active one, you can use `phpinfo()`:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Will be something similar to this:

[image]

Also, if there isn't a `php.ini` configuration file to load, PHP will simply use the default configurations (which can be seeen using `phpinfo();` as suggested above.

Comment: @Downvoter: care to explain?

Comment: I'm running XAMPP on OSX but without `php.ini` file it is just working fine. `Loaded Configuration File` has the value `(None)`. If I put the `php.ini` file back, it will show the location of the `php.ini` file. But if I accidently make an error in the `php.ini` file, apache is also just working fine. Can't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

You have either renamed the wrong PHP file, in that case see @Amal Mauralis' answer, in other case. PHP will load it's default configurations as a fail safe method.. So for example, if you have the running extensions:

- curl
- Mysqli library
- MSSQL/Sybase

these libraries will stop working, as PHP will be working with it's default configuration/minimal installation settings.